# Convert a client datetime to server datetime in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, date

I have a simple model like:

```
[MyRequired(Error = "Invalid date time")]
public DateTime LastUpdate
{
   get;set;
}

...
```

and `MyRequiredAttribute` class:

```
public class MyRequiredAttribute: RequiredAttribute {
   public override IsValid(object value) {
        //value get from request is `01/01/0001 00:00:00 ...`
        DateTime parsedTime = DateTime.Parse(value.ToString());

        // here throws exception
   }
}
```

and on Javascript side, using `Datepicker` plugin, I used

```
<input type="text" id="LastUpdate" name="LastUpdate" class="datepicker" value="<%=DateTime.Now.ToString( "dd-MM-yyyy" )%>" />
```

and

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
```

Every time, I receive from request `01/01/0001` value and throws an error that format is not correct.

How can I convert from `dd-MM-yyyy` format to `MM/dd/yyyy` format ? Maybe MVC accepts only `MM/dd/yyyy` format.

Comment: Checkout the IFormatProvider. You can specific the format of the inbound string that you are trying to parse. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kc8s65zs(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should write

```
$("#dates").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd-mm-yy");   // it will give format dd-mm-yy
```

or

```
$("#dates").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "mm-dd-yy"); // it will give format mm-dd-yy
```

Insted of

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
```

or on server side You can do something like this

```
const string dateformate = "dd/MM/yyyy";
var reachDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dates, dateformate, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This will convert any date to dd/MM/yyyy format.

Comment: No client side is porblem. Is just from server...On server side I want to do conversion.

Comment: Your solution works for `public string LastUpdate` instead of `public DateTime LastUpdate`

Answer (score 0):

In your Model use following way

```
public string LastUpdate
{
  get;set;
}
```

Now in your Controller Bind following way if it is in Editing Mode than

```
Model.LastUpdate = FetchDateFromServer.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")

otherwise

Model.LastUpdate = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
```

Now from your View Remove value from input type="text"  it will take if it is strongly typed

```
<input type="text" id="LastUpdate" name="LastUpdate" class="datepicker" />
```

I hope it will work as it is perfectly working in my project

Comment: `value` is object. If I do `value as Datetime` then gives me `01-01-0001`

Comment: @SnakeEyes So simply when you fetch convert it to Proper format which I have shown in next example for first time you can use DateTime.UtcNow

Comment: @SnakeEyes I have updated my answer . It may be helpful to you .

Comment: I want to parse what I receive from Http request, not date now.